# How to disable localhost:9000 in mobile?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I downloaded an application on my Android, and when I tried to open, the only thing that happened was Chrome trying to open a page called `localhost:9000`.

I've tried deleting the app, but my browser still keeps trying to open the localhost page, the number is already at 9008.

I'm a newbie in software so I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Clear data of Chrome app and then see if the issue resolves.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you mention/link the downloaded app just in case it may help the potential answerers? Also, try to close all the tabs, then check the Chrome settings for the current homepage.

Comment: It's me the guest who posted this question, so I discovered that even after closing all tabs it doesnt help, by the way I remember downloading from a mp4 site, it was supposed to be a normal video, but then the name of the app was: 1836229.apk.mp4 after trying to open this started to happen. And I guess you mean deleting the data itself from the app instead of the history?

Comment: If that's the case, then your device is possibly infected by malware. Sorry, I can't provide assistance in troubleshooting the malware, other than trying a factory reset.